# Don't ack RabbitMQ messages until IntegrationFlow service activator method returns succesfully?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-rabbit, spring-integration-amqp

I have an integration flow defined like this:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "queueName")
                    .id("id")
                    .autoStartup(autoStartup)
                    .concurrentConsumers(2)
                    .maxConcurrentConsumers(3)
                    .messageConverter(messageConverter()))
                    .aggregate(a -> ...)
                    .handle(serviceActivatorBean, "myMethod", e -> e.advice(requestHandlerRetryAdviceForIntegrationFlow()))
                    .get();
```

Where the `serviceActivatorBean` is defined like this:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ServiceActivator {

    @ServiceActivator    
    public void myMethod(Collection<MyEvent> events) {
        ....
    }    
}
```

And `requestHandlerRetryAdviceForIntegrationFlow()` is defined like this:

```
  public static RequestHandlerRetryAdvice requestHandlerRetryAdviceForIntegrationFlow() {
    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(MAX_VALUE);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    retryTemplate.setListeners(new RetryListenerSupport[]{new RetryListenerSupport() {
        @Override
        public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
            log.error("Caught exception {} (retry count {}), will retry again!", throwable.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    context.getRetryCount(), throwable);
        }
    }});
    advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(5000L);
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(200L);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    return advice;
}
```

The problem we face is when the `events` collection in the service activator contains 2 or more events and for some reason the processing of  `myMethod` fails and the server crash. What seems to happen is that the `IntegrationFlow` consumes and acks one message at a time from RabbitMQ, so if the server crash during the processing of `myMethod` all but the last event is lost. This is neither good nor safe enough for us. Is there something we can do to configure the `IntegrationFlow` to NOT ack any message until `myMethod` in the service activator has been completed successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Acknowledge Mode MANUAL and confirm via headers afterward:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-channel-adapter

Comment: Thanks, but is the recommended approach to achieve this? For example should I do this from within the service activator method or is there perhaps a "service activator post hook" that is better suited for this?

Comment: Right, there is: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice